# Not getting a queryset from Django model

Tags: python, django

I have made a custom endpoint in Django and I am trying to get a queryset for all the result records. This is inside a view, if that helps.

Here's my code (instead of print, I am technically using the python logging, but that shouldn't cause any problems here):

```
def item_get(request):
    item = Items.objects.all()
    print(item)
    for i in Items.objects.all():
        print(i)
```

This gives me nothing, but the exact same script with another model works just fine.

My model looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from encrypted_fields import EncryptedCharField
from encrypted_fields import EncryptedIntegerField
from encrypted_fields import EncryptedDateTimeField

class Items(models.Model):
    item_id = EncryptedCharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    item_date = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    item_date2 = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    last_viewed = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    dateitemsent = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    itemotherid = EncryptedCharField(max_length=100)
    itemsent = EncryptedIntegerField()
    itemret = EncryptedIntegerField()
    dateitemret = EncryptedDateTimeField()
```

Why would the query not be working with this app? The app is in the settings.py and there is definitely data in the database - I've inserted it manually.

Comment: Sure you have Item objects in db? What is it returning?

Comment: What does `print(item)` returns? I think it would be an empty queryset returning `[]`.

Comment: I absolutely do, they're in the proper database (items_items).

print(item) returns nothing. I am technically sending it to the python logging function, but figured print would be easier for people here to replicate. As far as I can tell, nothing is being sent/generated. This is not the case for my other model.

Comment: Can you do `str(Items.objects.all().query())` and post the output?

Comment: have you test 'Items.objects.all()' in the shell? python manage.py shell

Comment: I haven't, but now that I've tried it, it's throwing an error about a column value not being an integer. Let me test if that is related to the dummy data I inserted in, or if it is related to the encrypted fields I am using. We may be on the way to a solution.

Comment: I think you need a `manage migrate initial` or whatever it was called with a dryrun parm to indicate the table is already there.

Comment: Yep, got it @Andres. It was ultimately because the Encrypted Fields are all text, but it was expecting an Integer value inside the field. I'd imagine this is something of an edge case. I'm happy to write up the answer, or you can and take the credit as you led to the solution.